# How Many Squares Can Be Obtained By Drawing 6 Same-Sized Squares?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Question is very understandable. We have 6 of the same-sized squares. By putting/using them together, how many squares can we get at max?

For instance; if we would have 2 same-sized squares, we could get 3 squares by putting them from middle and corner. 2 from our original squares and 1 from intersection.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with solving? Please share what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried it with 3 and 4 squares to see if I could have pattern here.

For 1 square, 1 square.
For 2 squares, 3 squares.
For 3 squares, 7 squares.
For 4 squares, 11 squares. (not very sure about that one)

Apparently no clear pattern or I have calculated wrong.

Now I am susp about if (2^x)-1 is our answer or not.

Comment: This would be better on puzzling.se

Comment: For 3 squares to start my overlapping pattern gives 8 and 4 gives 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram that gets $41$.  I don't know if it is maximal

[image]
For $n$ initial squares, the number in this pattern is $3n-3$ plus twice [A002623(n-2)](http://oeis.org/A002623)  except for $n=1$ it is $1$, not $0$.  The twice A002623 accounts for the two stairsteps on the sides, and the $3n-3$ gets the main diagonal.  This gives the sequence for number of squares in this pattern as $1,3,8,15,26,41,62,89,124,167$.  This is not in OEIS